# How to host my own cloud so that videos are viewable via desktop web browser?

Tags: video, nas, streaming, cloud

I want to host my own cloud storage solution, something like Dropbox but entirely dependent on my own central machine. This way things are more secure if setup correctly, and there are artificial storage limitations or pay-walls. Some thing similar to ownCloud: http://owncloud.org/

There is one important feature I want to have: the ability the stream movies in a web browser from my personal cloud to anywhere in the world.

In the past I tried this with a NAS, and I mapped XBMC to the NAS via SFTP, and certain media types could stream in this manner. I've also used things like PLEX. In this case, I am looking for a single solution for personal cloud storage and movie streaming from that cloud into a web browser.

Does anyone know if this can be accomplished? Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: If you're only using a single machine, it's not a cloud.

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify... I want a single, centralized machine to sling/selectively sync media to multiple other machines, both local and remote. So my server would be the like the dropbox server, and all other computers the clients... which is a cloud.

Comment: For single-machine dependence, why not setup a FTP server? For streaming, there is support in VLC for a HTML/HTTP based server and client but AFAIK it's flaky.

Answer (score 1):

For streaming I would recommend you try [Emit](https://www.emitapp.com). You install the software on your server and you can then set it up so that you can view it in any browser or on Android, iOS or even Google TV.

There are other alternatives available, but so far this one has worked for me to stream almost any video anywhere, even with subtitles.

For the synchronization of files though, you will need a piece of program that will synchronize with the server. If your server runs on Linux a very good alternative is rsync. It is a small program that allows you to connect to a server and sync down specific files or folders. It can be set up to work syncing up as well. [rsync comes with a Windows version](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync) also. Since you didn't specify your choice of server OS I will not go into more detail on this but invite you to look up resources through Google. There's a lot of information out there on how to use rsync.

Lastly, a cloud is a group of servers working together to serve one or more features to one or more users in such a way that the user never knows if it is one or more computers that actually does the job. Yes I know this is very unspecific and even a little too simple. It has little to do with being a server accessible to several users. I understand what you want to do, but it's called simply setting up a server, or a home server if you like.